# Where are external Vaadin requests handled?

Tags: java, http, vaadin, external

Where are external Vaadin requests handled and how can I change their behavior?

For example:

```
String url = "http://anyhost.com/image.jpg";
Image i = new Image();
i.setSource(new ExternalResource(url));
```

Is there some sort of RequestHandler for ExternalResources?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The URL is just passed down in that case for `ExternalResource` to the **client**, the browser.  If you try above code, you will see, that you get an error, that the image can not be loaded in your devtools.  The generated HTML code (e.g. Inspect Element) is just `<img src="http://anyhost.com/image.jpg" .../>`.  The server part does not fetch that resource and "host" it for the client.

Or as the [docs](https://vaadin.com/api/7.5.0/com/vaadin/server/ExternalResource.html) state:

> ExternalResource implements source for resources fetched from location specified by URL:s. The resources are fetched directly by the client terminal and are not fetched trough the terminal adapter.

Comment: Ah ok that explains a lot. Thanks for your quick help.